# Align CheckBox in a dialog

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, jcheckbox

I want to align a check box(red highlighted area) According to other respective fields.

[image]

This is main method I am using to generate this

```
public class DialogTesting extends JFrame{

public static void main(String args[])
{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(320,250);
    frame.setLocation(400,400);

    JTextField txtUserName,txtHostName,txtPortNo,txtSID;
    JPasswordField txtPassword;
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JCheckBox chkBoxSaveConnection;

    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 210));
    mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    JLabel l_label = null;
    txtUserName = new JTextField("K_USERNAME", 15);
    txtUserName.putClientProperty("maxlength", 200);
    l_label = new JLabel("User Name");
    l_label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
    mainPanel.add(l_label);
    mainPanel.add(txtUserName);

    txtPassword = new JPasswordField("K_PASSWORD", 15);
    txtUserName.putClientProperty("maxlength", 200);
    l_label = new JLabel("Password");
    l_label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
    mainPanel.add(l_label);
    mainPanel.add(txtPassword);

    txtHostName = new JTextField("K_HOSTNAME", 15);
    txtHostName.putClientProperty("maxlength", 200);
    l_label = new JLabel("Host Name");
    l_label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
    mainPanel.add(l_label);
    mainPanel.add(txtHostName);

    txtPortNo = new JTextField("K_PORTNO", 15);

    l_label = new JLabel("Port Number");
    l_label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
    txtPortNo.putClientProperty("maxlength", 200);
    mainPanel.add(l_label);
    mainPanel.add(txtPortNo);


    txtSID = new JTextField("K_SID", 15);
    l_label = new JLabel("SID number");
    l_label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
    txtPortNo.putClientProperty("maxlength", 200);
    mainPanel.add(l_label);
    mainPanel.add(txtSID);

    chkBoxSaveConnection = new JCheckBox();
    l_label = new JLabel("chkBoxSaveConnection");
    l_label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 30));
    mainPanel.add(l_label);
    mainPanel.add(chkBoxSaveConnection);

    mainPanel.setVisible(true);

    frame.add(mainPanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Here I want to make check box(Red Highlighted area) align according to other fields

I tried this solution to make it align properly

```
mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout()); 
GridBagConstraints l_bag_constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
l_bag_constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
mainPanel.add(jlabel,FieldMapperHelper.getGridBagCompPosition(l_bag_constraints,0,0,10,1,0,10)
            );
    mainPanel.add(txtUserName
            ,FieldMapperHelper.getGridBagCompPosition(l_bag_constraints,0,1,10,1,0,10)
            );
```

But in this case it is showing me very small text box.

Please let me know if you want any thing else apart from it.

Comment: How did you do it for the other fields? Simply do the same for the checkbox. Optionnally, you can also use [`setLabelFor(Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setLabelFor(java.awt.Component))

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Guillaume Polet How can i do same thing for checkbox also as both of the component have different-different properties(For a reference please check, have updated my post).Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @ David Kroukamp Have updated my post.Please check.

Comment: Please read the document linked by @DavidKroukamp  - what is posted is not an SSCCE.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson I think i have done with required changes to make my post is an SSCCE post.Please let me know if something is missing.

Comment: @Sunil: No `main(String[])`--> not an SSCCE. Not compilable--> not an SSCCE either. What is `mainPanel`? What is its `LayoutManager`? There are tons of information missing. Now, I really don't see how you cannot create another `JLabel` and `JCheckbox` and add them to your `mainPanel` in the same manner as you did for other fields. Finally, setting the preferred size of your component is really not a good idea and is likely to lead to more problems than solutions. Cheers.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet Thanks for your guidance, have done the required changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so your problem is that you don't use an appropriate LayoutManager and you are also forced to set preferred sizes (you should simply never do that).

Here is an update version of your code which uses `GridBagLayout` and should works nicely:

[image: Result image]

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DialogTesting {

    protected void initUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextField txtUserName, txtHostName, txtPortNo, txtSID;
        JPasswordField txtPassword;
        JPanel mainPanel;
        JCheckBox chkBoxSaveConnection;

        GridBagConstraints firstCol = new GridBagConstraints();
        firstCol.weightx = 1.0;
        firstCol.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        firstCol.insets = new Insets(5, 20, 5, 5);

        GridBagConstraints lastCol = new GridBagConstraints();
        lastCol.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        lastCol.weightx = 1.0;
        lastCol.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        lastCol.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 20);

        mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        JLabel l_label = null;
        txtUserName = new JTextField("K_USERNAME", 15);
        txtUserName.putClientProperty("maxlength", 200);
        l_label = new JLabel("User Name");
        mainPanel.add(l_label, firstCol);
        mainPanel.add(txtUserName, lastCol);

        txtPassword = new JPasswordField("K_PASSWORD", 15);
        txtUserName.putClientProperty("maxlength", 200);
        l_label = new JLabel("Password");
        mainPanel.add(l_label, firstCol);
        mainPanel.add(txtPassword, lastCol);

        txtHostName = new JTextField("K_HOSTNAME", 15);
        txtHostName.putClientProperty("maxlength", 200);
        l_label = new JLabel("Host Name");
        mainPanel.add(l_label, firstCol);
        mainPanel.add(txtHostName, lastCol);

        txtPortNo = new JTextField("K_PORTNO", 15);

        l_label = new JLabel("Port Number");
        txtPortNo.putClientProperty("maxlength", 200);
        mainPanel.add(l_label, firstCol);
        mainPanel.add(txtPortNo, lastCol);

        txtSID = new JTextField("K_SID", 15);
        l_label = new JLabel("SID number");
        txtPortNo.putClientProperty("maxlength", 200);
        mainPanel.add(l_label, firstCol);
        mainPanel.add(txtSID, lastCol);

        chkBoxSaveConnection = new JCheckBox();
        l_label = new JLabel("chkBoxSaveConnection");
        mainPanel.add(l_label, firstCol);
        mainPanel.add(chkBoxSaveConnection, lastCol);

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DialogTesting().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.Is there any default value of Insets for gridbaylayout.If yes then can you please put some light into it also.

Comment: @Sunil No, the layout itself does not generate default insets, since you have the possibility to set them on the `GridBagConstraint`. The default insets of a `GridBagConstraint` are `new Insets(0,0,0,0)`.